# How to create Multiple column addition in PySpark just like in SAS if then do statement (no else)?

Tags: pyspark, sas

I wish to convert the below SAS code to PySpark, could anyone help me on this ?

```
data ABC_New;
set ABC(where=(A=1234));
format C z14.;
 if A ge 0 then do;
    C=A*50000;
    X1 = input(substr(put(C,z14.),1,2),2.);
    X2 = input(substr(put(C,z14.),3,2),2.);
    X3  =input(substr(put(C,z14.),1,1)||substr(put(C,z14.),3,1),2.);
    X4  =input(substr(put(C,z14.),2,1)||substr(put(C,z14.),4,1),2.);
  end;
run;
```

Appreciate any help !

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a moment to read about how to post spark questions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples

Comment: What did you try?  Do you need help with the IF/THEN/DO or converting the PUT/INPUT logic?

Answer (score 0):

There are many differences between SAS and python and pyspark. Here are some highlights:

We transform the data by defining steps in an execution pipeline.

```py
(ABC
  # Filter the data in the pipeline to just rows where A is 1234.
  .filter(ABC.A == 1234)
  # We can only create one column at a time, but these columns
  # can be nested. We have to define the transformation that produces this column separately.
  .withColumn('X', my_udf(ABC.A)))
```

Here we define the function to perform our transformation in the execution pipeline:

```py
def my_func(A):
  # Exit early if A is not greater than or equal to zero.
  if A < 0:
    return (None, None, None, None) # NOTE: we must return 4 columns.

  C = A * 50000 # This is the same in almost every language ;)
  padded = C.zfill(14) # Save our padded string ("z-filled") to be reused
  X1 = int(padded[0:2]) # Here we slice the string to get a substring from ,and including, the 0 index to, but not including, the 2 index
  X2 = int(padded[2:4])
  X3 = int(padded[0] + padded[2])
  X4 = int(padded[1] + padded[3])
  return (X1, X2, X3, X4) # We return all four values packed in a "tuple". They'll be nested below our parent column in the new dataset.
```

Here we define the types and columns that our transformation function will return.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType

schema = StructType([ # A struct is a data structure that holds other datastructures
    StructField("X1", IntegerType()),
    StructField("X2", IntegerType()),
    StructField("X3", IntegerType()),
    StructField("X4", IntegerType())
])

my_udf = udf(my_func, schema) # We define a function for use in pyspark, by combining a python function with a pyspark schema.
```

Here's what the schema looks like.

```
root
 |-- X: struct    (nullable = true)
 |   |-- X1: int  (nullable = true)
 |   |-- X2: int  (nullable = true)
 |   |-- X3: int  (nullable = true)
 |   |-- X4: int  (nullable = true)
```